# TAB completion not working for mounted partition

Tags: command-line, partitioning, bash, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm used to mount a Windows partition (E) into my Windows Subsystem for Linux (running Ubuntu 20.04) by giving the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/e
sudo mount -t drvfs E: /mnt/e
```

Unfortunately, writing in a shell, TAB completion of directories or files for such partition does not work (even if it works well for all the rest).

Things already tried:

- the E partition seems to be mounted correctly, since `ls /mnt/e` shows all the directories and files within it
- it makes no difference launching WSL with `wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc`
- putting a `test.xslx` file in the home directory and giving `compgen -f t` results in `test.xlsx` as output. However, moving into the Windows partition (E) and trying `compgen -f i` where `i` is the initial character of the `images` folder, which really exists in E, nothing is printed. Typing `ls i` and then hitting TAB doesn't complete the word. The output of `bind -q complete` is `complete can be invoked via "\C-i", "\e\e".`

How could I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A heads-up that [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/902710) the [same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702839/432493) to multiple Stack Exchange sites is not recommended.  You should probably wait a few more days on the first one.  But at the least, make sure to reference everything that you've already tried (See [Search and Research](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)) in this question so that folks don't waste your time or theirs suggesting things that you've already tried.  Thanks!

Comment: One thing to help narrow the issue down might be `compgen -f x` where `x` is the initial character of one or more known files in the current directory. That should tell us whether it is completion itself that is broken, or the keybinding between TAB and the completion function.

Comment: @steeldriver putting only a `test.xslx` file in the home directory and giving `compgen -f t` results in `test.xlsx` as output

Comment: ... but typing `ls t` and then hitting TAB doesn't complete? What is the output of `bind -q complete`?

Comment: @steeldriver moving into the Windows partition (E) and trying `compgen -f i` where `i` is the initial character of the `images` folder, which really exists in E, nothing is printed. Typing `ls i` and then hitting TAB doesn't complete the word. The output of `bind -q complete` is `complete can be invoked via "\C-i", "\e\e".`

Comment: @user9952796 Still noodling here.  Is there any `/etc/wsl.conf`?  If so, what are its contents?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds no, there isn't any `wsl.conf` in `/etc`